# Is there any way we can cast RemoteWebDriver as AndroidDriver

Tags: selenium, appium-android

1.Creating a page in which declaring driver as RemoteDriver.
2.Calling a function where again I’m declaring a driver as RemoteDriver.
3.Running a test where I’m declaring driver as RemoteDriver.
4.Trying to access the AppiumDriver method in my test method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and solved it using the below code.

```
Public class DriverManager {

private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
private static AppiumDriver driver;
private static DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

public void initDriver(String browser){

   if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){

   caps.setCapability("");
   ....
   ....

   webDriver.set(driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("<<.../hub>>"), caps));

   }

 }

 public AppiumDriver getDriver() throws Exception {

    return driver;

   }
}
```